# error conexión base de datos php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Buenos dias al tratar de conectarme en php de la siguiente manera:

```
$hs="localhost:8080";
$us="docunet";
$pw="docunet";
$dbse="docunet";

$conect = mysqli_connect($hs, $us, $pw) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");
 $db = mysqli_select_db( $conect, $dbse ) or die ( "Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos" );

mysqli_close( $conexion );
```

me salen estas advertencias y un fatal error pero no se que sea:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\docunetmy\config.php on line 9
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet.
>   PID=9544 in C:\xampp\htdocs\docunetmy\config.php on line 9 Warning:
>   mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\docunetmy\config.php on line 9 Fatal error: Maximum
>   execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\docunetmy\config.php on line 9

de antemano agradezco su colaboración

tambien lo he intentado asi:

```
$hs="localhost:8080";
$us="docunet";
$pw="docunet";
$dbse="docunet";


$conect = mysqli_connect($hs, $us, $pw,$dbse);

if (!$conect) {
    echo "Error: No se pudo conectar a MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "errno de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "error de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Éxito: Se realizó una conexión apropiada a MySQL! La base de datos mi_bd es genial." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Información del host: " . mysqli_get_host_info($conect) . PHP_EOL;
```

pero el mensaje es el mismo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de este modo:

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'password';
$database = 'dbname';

$conexion = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);

echo ($conexion) ? 'Conectado' : 'no conectado';
```

> Debes quitar esto `:8080` pues ese no es el puerto del servidor de
>   mysql, el cual de hecho es 3306, pero no es necesario declararlo

Entonces el detalle esta en

```
'localhot:8080'
```

Que debería ser

```
'localhost'
```

Comment: excelente, Gracias, como ese es el puerto que uso para el xampp, pense que iba siempre.

Comment: @emoreno2018 de nada recuerda que si la respuesta te sirvió la marques como aceptada

Comment: que pena mi ignorancia pero no veo donde se marca como aceptada @alfredopaz

Comment: basta con que des clic a la palomita que esta en tono gris, misma acción que la pondrá de tono verde y con eso queda como aceptada @emoreno2018